# Regex to match alphanumeric except specific substring

Tags: c#, regex

**Edit:
MANDATORY CONDITION:
Regex has to be inserted into the following statement:**

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<REGEX_STRING>");
val= regex.Matches(val).Cast<Match>().Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + e.Value, s => s);
```

I found out that I can't use `Regex.Replace()` method as it was suggested in the answer below.

***I am looking for a RegEx that would have to follow two conditions:***

1. accept only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, \s (one or more), and ignore `_` (that's why `\w` is not an option)
2. **[!]** exclude any `{sq}` "substring" anywhere inside the string

*`{sq}` - it's literally this 4-chars string, not any shortcut for ASCII sign !

---

***What I have so far is:***

**`\b(?!sq)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*`**

but this RegEx cuts everything when `_` shows up + it also excludes i.e whole `[sq]`.
So for example for a given string:

`test[sq]uirrel{sq}_things` I should get `testsquirrelthings` and what I get is: `testuirrel`

---

Small `input | expected output` table below:

| Input string | Expected output |
| --- | --- |
| `Na#me` | `Name` |
| `M2a_ny` | M2any |
| `Vari{sq}o@us` | `Various` |
| `test [sq]uirrel h23ere!` | `test squirrel h23ere` |

I would really appreciate any help, it's the most complicated RegEx I have ever came across

Comment: Can one pair of `{}` be inside another `{}`?

Comment: Maybe remove them? `Regex.Replace(text, @"{sq}|[^a-zA-Z\s]", "")`?

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory: you say "_accept only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, \s (one or more)_" but then give an example `M2a_ny` -> `Many` where the `2` is removed.

Comment: @Backs yes, it's possible that inputString will come in form of sth like test{{sq}}ing, but it should also be fully rejected. So result would be -> testing. I don't know if that answers Your question

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay my bad! Will fix it immediately. It SHOULD BE M2any. Same for h23ere

Comment: I  hope you understand that your "MANDATORY CONDITION" cannot be met, do you?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it is not possible in .NET regex to match any text but a *multicharacter sequence*.

You will have to use a terrible workaround like

```cs
((?:(?!{sq})[A-Za-z0-9\s])+)|{sq}
```

and you will need to get Group 1 values. See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%7Bsq%7D%29%5BA-Za-z0-9%5Cs%5D%29%2B%29%7C%7Bsq%7D&i=Na%23me%09Name%0D%0AM2a_ny%09M2any%0D%0AVari%7Bsq%7Do%40us%09Various%0D%0Atest%20%5Bsq%5Duirrel%20h23ere!%09test%20squirrel%20h23ere). Here is a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ufJIVo):

```cs
var texts = new List<string> { "Na#me","M2a_ny","Vari{sq}o@us","test [sq]uirrel h23ere!" };
var pattern = @"((?:(?!{sq})[A-Za-z0-9\s])+)|{sq}";
    foreach (var text in texts) {
    var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>()
            .Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + e.Groups[1].Value, s => s);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
// => Name, M2any, Various, test squirrel h23ere
```

**A better, `Regex.Replace` based solution**
You can remove `{sq}` and all non-letter and non-whitespace chars using

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"{sq}|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "")
Regex.Replace(text, @"{sq}|[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]", "")
```

The `\p{L}` / `\p{N}` version can be used to support any Unicode letters/digits.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7bsq%7d%7c%5b%5ea-zA-Z0-9%5cs%5d&i=Na%23me%09Name%0d%0aM2a_ny%09M2any%0d%0aVari%7bsq%7do%40us%09Various%0d%0atest+%5bsq%5duirrel+h23ere!%09test+squirrel+h23ere&r=):

[image]

Comment: Situation changed a little bit: this solution works, but I can't use it. I will have to use the same approach in code: val = regex.Matches(val).Cast<Match>().Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + e.Value, s => s);

Comment: @KamilTurowski Well, the problem is that it is not possible in .NET regex to match any text but a *multicharacter sequence*. You will have to use a terrible workaround like `Regex.Matches(text, @"((?:(?!{sq})[A-Za-z0-9\s])+)|{sq}").Cast<Match>().Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + e.Groups[1].Value, s => s)`.

Comment: You can't make it with `e.Value`, sorry.